# Offset UITableView Content When Keyboard Appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I'm getting the error:
Property 'editingIndexPath' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'  with the line:
`[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.editingIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];`

The error has something to do with this call:  `self.editingIndexPath`

How would I fix this error?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
        contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.height), 0.0);
    } else {
        contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.width), 0.0);
    }

    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.editingIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler tells you everything. Just define a `editingIndexPath` property.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *editingIndexPath
```