# Error in Offsetting UITableView Content When Keyboard Appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

This question was already asked here

> [Offset UITableView Content When Keyboard Appears](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23716534/5395919)

in objective C. I had tried to implement the accepted answer in Swift but in vain.

I have a TableView in which I want to offset the table view when the keyboard appears and I have wrote the code as follows -

In **viewWillAppear()**

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

And then -

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        let contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets!
         let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
         if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation)
         {
            contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize!.height), 0.0)
          }
        else
         {
            contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize!.width), 0.0)
          }
        self.TableVieww.contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.TableVieww.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;



        TableVieww.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(self.editingIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)

    }
```

But I am getting error as -  **value of type 'SearchVC' has no property 'editingIndexPath'**.

Comment: Have you defined editingIndexPath in your code?

Comment: Ya I had tried  let editingIndexPath = NSIndexPath().